# Getting "QObject: Cannot create children for a parent that is in a different thread" error in Visual Studio 2017 while no problem in QTCreator

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, qt5, qtcpsocket

I am at the beginning of a POC task and get the exact code from this address:
https://www.bogotobogo.com/Qt/Qt5_QTcpSocket_Signals_Slots.php

While the code works perfectly in Qt Creator, I get he error **QObject: Cannot create children for a parent that is in a different thread** when I try to run the same code in Visual Studio in the line `socket = new QTcpSocket(this);`
My Visual Studio version is 2017, Qt version is 5.9.9. I use the same QT version on both QT Creator and Visual Studio.

I have checked related posts but all mention about creating a thread. I don't create a thread.

Here is the code:
mytcpsocket.h

```
#ifndef MYTCPSOCKET_H
#define MYTCPSOCKET_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QtNetwork/qtcpsocket.h>
#include <QDebug>

class MyTcpSocket : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit MyTcpSocket(QObject *parent = 0);

    void doConnect();

signals:

public slots:
    void connected();
    void disconnected();
    void bytesWritten(qint64 bytes);
    void readyRead();

private:
    QTcpSocket *socket;

};

#endif // MYTCPSOCKET_H
```

mytcpsocket.cpp

```
#ifndef MYTCPSOCKET_H
#define MYTCPSOCKET_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QtNetwork/qtcpsocket.h>
#include <QDebug>

class MyTcpSocket : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit MyTcpSocket(QObject *parent = 0);

    void doConnect();

signals:

public slots:
    void connected();
    void disconnected();
    void bytesWritten(qint64 bytes);
    void readyRead();

private:
    QTcpSocket *socket;

};

#endif // MYTCPSOCKET_H
```

And the main.cpp

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include "mytcpsocket.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    MyTcpSocket s;
    s.doConnect();
    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Answer (score 0):

about Qobject these notes are important:

> The child of a QObject must always be created in the thread where the
> parent was created. This implies, among other things, that you should
> never pass the QThread object (this) as the parent of an object
> created in the thread (since the QThread object itself was created in
> another thread).
>
> Event driven objects may only be used in a single thread.
> Specifically, this applies to the timer mechanism and the network
> module. For example, you cannot start a timer or connect a socket in a
> thread that is not the object's thread.
>
> You must ensure that all objects created in a thread are deleted
> before you delete the QThread. This can be done easily by creating the
> objects on the stack in your run() implementation.

read more in [QObject Reentrancy](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/threads-qobject.html#qobject-reentrancy)